# Tar each top level directory separately

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, tar

How can I create tarballs for a series of directories?

E.g. if my home directory contains directories called “one” “two” “three” and “four” how can I create one.tar.gz two.tar.gz three.tar.gz and four.tar.gz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for dir in one two three four; do
    tar_file_name="$dir".tar.gz
    test -f "$tar_file_name" || tar -czf "$tar_file_name" "$dir"
done
```

With all directory names (real directories, not symlinks):

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob

for dir in *; do
    test -d "$dir" && test ! -L "$dir" || continue
    tar_file_name="$dir".tar.gz
    test -f "$tar_file_name" || tar -czf "$tar_file_name" "$dir"
done
```

Comment: Almost perfect. Is there a way to make this fetch all the directory names instead of hard coding them? I used one two three four as an example but it’s actually about 50 directories all named different things…

Comment: @Dr-McGillicuddy Adapted my answer.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you!